# What is the difference between $(document).ready(function() and $(function() ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I know what this does:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your code here...
});
```

Now I have seen people doing this lately:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(function(){
    // Your code here...
});
</script>
```

Are these two ways of doing the same thing?

I see an anonymous function being declared inside a jquery selector here, but never actually being invoked, yet by the way the page runs it seems that this may just run on pageload.

Comment: Lately? This has been available for the last 5 years....

Comment: That's one of the things I dislike about jquery... in pursuit of brevity, it seriously sacrifices (re)discoverability. IIRC, `$(...)` can do at least three completely different things, depending on the type of the argument, and how do you look up such a thing? You can *if you're familiar with the docs* - and that's precisely the point. The language is designed for those who stay familiar with its details. `</rant>`

Comment: P.S. In this case, if you remember that `$` is an alias for `jQuery`, you can look it up here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes, they're doing the same thing.  the `$()` function wraps `$(document).ready()` when the parameter to the call is a single function object.

(Edited to reflect a question in comment)

Comment: So whenever you use a jquery selector a quiet little document ready check is happening in the background?

Comment: No, jQuery checks the type of the object passed to it and if it is a function it is bound to the document's ready event; if it's passed a string, it will do something else (like select DOM elements).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are doing exactly the same thing.

```
$(function(){
    // Your code here...
});
```

is a shortcut for

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your code here...
});
```