# $(function(){});, (function($)(){}(JQuery); and $(document).ready(function(){}); any difference?

Tags: jquery

I have a very strange issue with JQuery, its about a starting of JQuery code when document is ready, as I know there is no difference to use one of methods `$(function(){//CODE});`, `(function($)(){//CODE}(JQuery)` or `$(document).ready(function(){//CODE});`.

Like what said on [What is the difference between $(document).ready(function() and $(function() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593292/what-is-the-difference-between-document-readyfunction-and-function)

So I like always to use `$(function(){//CODE});` method, but when I using this method in some pages working well, but in another I got errors like If I use `$.fn.extend` or `$.browser.msie` , I'll get '$.fn is undefined' issue, tried to use `(function($)(){//CODE}(JQuery)` and that error disappeared, I just want to know why this happening and really if there is and difference between each method !

Comment: I prefer start this way: `jQuery(function ($) {});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a javascript import in the offending page is redefining the `$` variable. This variable doesn't reference `jQuery` anymore, hence the error. When using the `(function($)(){//CODE}(JQuery)` construct, you create a closure where the `$` variable is once again bound to the jQuery object, and everything goes well inside this closure.

Another way to avoid problems is to always use `jQuery` instead of `$`. Example : `jQuery(function(){//CODE});`

Comment: You know what, It seems like as what you said, I replaced all $ with jQuery and that solved my problem, I just really wonder. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you're getting the error, you have set [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) (or someone has).

`$` is just an alias for `jQuery` - other frameworks use this too though.

There should be no problem using `$(function(){code})` ..or.. `jQuery(function(){code})`

Comment: Yes, I know if I have `$.noConflict` I'll get that, but the strange is I don't have it, I tried to search in source code but no result for `$.noConflict` .

Comment: @Al-Mothafar Are you using any other frameworks? And does the script tag referencing jQuery come before your own script tag?

Comment: hmm you shouldn't get a conflict with YUI. Can you post your code?

Comment: Its like any code with JQuery, its large and hard to put it, working well and this first time getting that issue while I'm testing, nothing special, any way replacing $ with jQuery solve my problem !