# How do $(function(){ // js to run }) and $(document).ready() differ?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the difference between $(document).ready(function() and $(function() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593292/what-is-the-difference-between-document-readyfunction-and-function)
>   [What is the difference between these jQuery ready functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/what-is-the-difference-between-these-jquery-ready-functions)

Furthermore, if they perform the same purpose, how does `$(function(){ // js to run })` translate to `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Wow, thanks. I need to search more thoroughly.

Comment: p.s; in answer to part II of your question (how do they map); [see here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/255460e4836e86b86f48dd5b7d2a2cbf3f996de2/src/core.js#L174)

Comment: $(function(){ does perform faster. But I cant explain the seasons for it. $.fn.ready() is faster still

Comment: Thanks! Essentially, if the factory function $() receives a function, the function is bound to the ready event. If $() receives a string, jQuery parses it as a selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they both do exactly the same thing.